# Approximating equation of motion with polynomial

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, simulations, approximations

I have set up these equations for a projectile in a game:

\begin{align}
y(t) &= 100 (-(0.99)^t (v \sin(\theta) + 100 g) + v \sin(\theta) + g (-t) + 100 g)\\
x(t) &= -100 (0.99^t - 1) v \cos(\theta)\end{align}

But I need the angle to hit the coordinates $(x,y)$ ($t$ has to be eliminated).

I tried a lot of things, but it seems impossible to solve the equation for the angle while eliminating $t$. So the next thing I heard about was the idea of transforming the equations to a polynomial. I don't know if that is possible and if there is a name for it, I could not find anything that fits my problem in the internet.

Comment: I've added MathJax to your equations, but those look awfully awkward for equations of motion, can you verify them?

Comment: Sure, the projectile is programmed awfully in the game, that's why the equations are also awful. It is because the air resistance is proportional to the velocity -> 1% of the velocity is subtracted every second. That means I created these recursive equations using wolfram alpha. I checked them in the game and they fit perfectly!

Comment: What do you mean with: "this is quite nice!"? :)

Comment: It's a neat yet simple model that appears applicable in real life.

Comment: Oh really?  I didn't think of that.

Comment: -1. This is a question about mathematics (solving equations) not physics.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you have known constants $v,\,g$ but need to obtain $t,\,\theta$ from $x,\,y$.

Your polynomial idea is to use the first few terms of $0.99^t=1+t\ln 0.99+\frac{t^2}{2}\ln^2 0.99+\cdots$. If you stop with the $t$ term, small-$t$ data have approximately $t$-independent expressions for $\dot{x},\,\dot{y}$ in terms of $\theta$. (More terms would complicate the matter.) You'd need to estimate a velocity from a change in position over a short time, but you'd still need to know some $t$ to do that. This hiccup was to be expected, actually, since the strategy, had it worked, would use two coordinates to get one, raising the question, "when did we find the other?" After all, as a rule of thumb we get $n$ unknowns from $n$ knowns.

So let's try a different method. You might work out a way to do it with Lambert's W, but it's probably easier to code a numerical method (computing $W$ needs this anyway). For example, the [Newton-Raphson method](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/103/lectures/newton.pdf) is a fast option. It helps that, since the Jacobian is a $2\times 2$ matrix here, it's easy to invert.

Comment: No, I don't need t, I just need θ. I already checked every way and it's not possible to do it with Lambert-W, I already tried that

Comment: Technically you don't want $t$, but you get it for free.

Comment: So you think I should solve the equation for a using Lambert-W? I tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Intektor No; I think you should use Newton-Raphson instead.